# Trigger intent after bot response

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

The dialogflow fulfillment code sample can return response in intent as follow.

```
function welcome(agent) {
  agent.add(`Welcome to agent!`);
}
```

Suppose that I want to trigger another intent name "faq" right after that **without any user input**. How can it be done? I am expecting something as follow but could not find any documentation.

```
function welcome(agent) {
  agent.add(`Welcome to agent!`);
  agent.triggerIntent('faq');
}
```

I look at the [custom event documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-custom) but still unable get the idea to implement it.

**Conversation sample:**

```
User A: Hi
Bot: Welcome to agent!
Bot: Please pick FAQ to see detail:
1) FAQ 1
2) FAQ 2
3) FAQ 3
User: Show FAQ
Bot: Please pick FAQ to see detail:
1) FAQ 1
2) FAQ 2
3) FAQ 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't do this. But you also don't need to.

Remember that an Intent represents *what the user has said* and not how you respond to that. So your welcome Intent can reply with a welcome message, and then the FAQ prompting. And a second Intent can reply with just the FAQ prompting.

The easiest way to do this is to have all your replies in your Fulfillment, and have both the handler for the "Welcome" Intent and the "FAQ" Intent call the same function that sends back the prompting reply.

Answer (score 1):

you are on the right track, you need to send an event to trigger another intent.

```
agent.setFollowupEvent('myEventName');
```

See [doc](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client#webhookclientsetfollowupeventevent) on how to set a followUp event. You also need to define the event in the Intent screen (after Contexts): once an event with that name (ie myEventName) is found the intent is triggered.

Comment: Hello, I put agent.add(`Welcome to agent!`); agent.setFollowUpEvent('faq');. Now the follow up event shown but the original 'Welcome to agent!' message not shown. I want the message 'Welcome to agent` show as well before followupEvent. How can it be done?

Comment: I see, I dont think this is possible (last event or response overrides what is sent before). One option for you (I think) it so to define in the Default Welcome Intent with 2 text responses (1. Welcome to agent. 2. Pick FAQ) in the DialogFlow UI. They would be sent to the user one after the other

Comment: I can do it that way, but that means that I need to repeat the code and logic. Since i need to have follow up event inside Pick FAQ intent and the pick faq intent can be trigger by other user input such as "show faq" as well in addition to showing in welcome alone. I am thinking if there is a more convenient way for that as this is quite a common scenario. I didn't see why such a feature is not available or i miss out something that can replace it.